# how to setup the environment for docker containers without exposing the ports

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

Docker is Installed in the AWS instance.
Multiple Web Applications and databases are running on docker containers.
Docker ports are mapped with AWS local host ports.
When AWS ports are blocked from the security groups, web applications and databases running on docker container goes down.
how to setup the environment without exposing the web app ports (i.e, AWS instance ports) to public network?

Comment: Can you say a little bit more about the problems you're having?  How would you deal with this if Docker weren't involved?

Answer (score 0):

The application running on that ports won't be getting down as the ports would be open locally. While accessing the application since the ports are blocked the request is not routed till the docker instances.

You can update the security group inbound rules to access the application within the VPC subnet. i.e in the CIDR block you can specify the IP range that will be routed to the docker services